# Как убрать несколько url?

Tags: url, joomla, чпу

Добрый день. У меня такой вопрос:

Есть сайт, у него на страницу создается почему-то 3 урл сразу, типа (путь `/product/view/цифра/цифра.html`) и нормальный с ЧПУ. Как запретить создание этих страниц? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: >  Есть сайт у него на страницу создается почему-то 3 урл сразу

Кем или чем и где создаётся?

> и нормальный с ЧПУ

А какой есть еще "не нормальный"?

> Как запретить содание этих страниц

Для начала надо разобраться с первым пунктом, где какой-то поганец "создает" эти страницы, ссылки, или ЧПУ )))

Comment: Вы используете CMS? Если да, то какую?

Comment: joomla joomshopping

Comment: http://домен/katalog/okna/okno-iz-sosnu.html
http://домен/evro-okna/product/view/6/8.html
http://домен/katalog/product/view/6/8.html
http://домен/osteklenie-balkonov/product/view/6/8.html
К примеру, одна и таже страница выводится
Простой каталог делаю.

Comment: Для  kohana подойдет такой вариант чпу ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам решил вопрос.

```
RedirectMatch ^([0-9a-zA-Z\/\-\_]*)product/view/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ http://домен/404.html
```